# How do I fill in the values of a foreign key when extracting data from a flat file into a relational database in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 tables

1 table with all the information which I want to extract to two tables

```
[flat file]

name / team / town

[team table]

teamID/ team / town

[person table]

personID/ name / teamID
```

now I can use INSERT INTO SELECT to fill the values of the team table but i have hit a roadblock because I cant find a way to put the corresponding teamID in with the team that they are in.

I tried something like this but it just ends up repeating the name with each and every teamID

```
INSERT INTO person(name,teamID)

SELECT DISTINCT name,teamID FROM file,team
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: Can we assume that `teamID` and `personID` are each AUTO_INCREMENT columns?

Comment: table definitions, sample data and desired outcome would be nice, as is I guess the fk is in person on teamid

Answer (score 1):

When you use Joins you will get the wanted results for your table

```
INSERT INTO person(name,teamID)    
SELECT DISTINCT f.name,t.teamID FROM file f  JOIN team t ON f.team = t.team AND f.town = t.town
```

Comment: +1. I suggest however you join on both `team` _and_ `town`. We don’t know the data set nor DDL, but that’d be a bit safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query below -

INSERT INTO person(name,teamID)
SELECT DISTINCT f.name,t.teamID
FROM file as f
JOIN team as t
ON f.teamID = t.teamID;